# How to enable faceted search in BigCommerce using Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

So I've got an enterprise store and I'm building a stencil template, and I've run into a roadblock with the product filters...

How do I show more than 15 items in the product filters? I've tried removing the {{#if show_more_toggle}} code from components/faceted-search/facets/multi.html, but all that does is make the Show More label appear; it doesn't actually do anything when clicked.

Either I'm missing something significant, or Stencil doesn't yet support showing more than 15 filters. Either way, a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been extended in blueprint themes, but Stencil is still limited to 15 items. This will be raised with the Stencil Project Manager.